# In this project, why am I unable to access my view's properties that I load from a nib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib, nib

Here's a sample project recreating the issue: http://cl.ly/3O3M232f1q0R

I created a `TutorialScreen` subclass of `UIView`, and in a xib file I created three `UIView`s of that type and used them in another class by bringing those objects into `UIView`s:

```
self.tutorialScreen1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
self.tutorialScreen1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.tutorialScreen1.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
self.tutorialScreen1.alpha = 0.0;
[self.notificationWindow addSubview:self.tutorialScreen1];
```

In the xib file, each `UIView` has a `UILabel` in the middle that I created an outlet for (and linked all three `UIView`s to), called `textLabel`.

But in that class I created `tutorialScreen1` in, when I do the following:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.tutorialScreen3.textLabel.text);
```

Every time that outputs `(null)`. Why on earth is it doing that? The label is explicitly set to "text" so I don't see why it keeps calling it null. I can't manipulate it at all because the label doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't connect the outlets:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Added an outlet to `textLabel` in the .h file still did nothing.

Comment: @Doug Smith That's not how you connect it. See the second screenshot.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with constraints as well? I'm trying to but failing miserably to be able to access them in code, even if I connect them in the above way. (Say I connect an Auto Layout constraint from the top of the text label to its superview.)

Comment: @Doug Smith I don't know :)

Comment: @DougSmith, yes you can make IBOutlets to layout constraints. You can make them from the constraints you see when you select a view, but sometimes it's easier to select them from the Scene list.